# missing sql services in sql server configuration manager and services

Tags: sql-server, service

I installed sql server management studio 17.9 and I want to know the server name so I use this command in command prompt (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager14.msc)
and when It was opened I can't get any item .. all I get is in the following pictured...
[image]

[image]

[image]

and whent I search for sql services in services I ca't find 
[image]

What can I do to solve this issues!!

Comment: Management Studio != Server. If all you've installed is management studio, you still don't have SQL Server itself installed. Your screenshots tend to confirm this is the case.

Comment: you mean microsoft sql server management studio is not include the server!! how can I instaled the server please??

Comment: No the Management Studio tools are to manage the instance - they can be installed on any client PC regardless of whether there is a database instance running on the host e.g. for end users/developers.

You have to re-run the installer and install a new database instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio is only a management tool. It doesn't install SQL Server. So most likely there is no SQL Server installed on this box.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the sql server and everything is going right.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing SQL server management studio.
I realized that I had not installed SQL Server. Follow this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) to install SQL server and then you will have the configuration manager.